# JavaScript IF / ELSE error - expected an identifier

Tags: javascript, identifier

I'm trying to learn JavaScript on Code Academy I am facing the following syntax problem. Tells me:

`expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'. Missing ';' before statement`

Here is the code:

```
If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);

{
    console.log("The answer makes sense!");

} 
else {

    console.log("Error. Error. Error.");
}
```

Comment: remove semicolon after if

Comment: Change the capital If to if

Comment: this question will attract hundred of answers :P

Comment: *sidenote:* `console.log` is not cross-browser. Old browsers will result in JavaScript error.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor He says he's working on codecademy so don't worry...

Answer (score 2):

Omit the `;` in `If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);`

The syntax of `if` is:

```
if(condition) {
  // what to happen
} else {
  // what to happen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon from the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
If ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) == 6) {
    console.log("The answer makes sense!");
} else {    
    console.log("Error. Error. Error.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon `;` after you `if` statement. Remove it. It should be:

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6) {

   console.log("The answer makes sense!");

} else {

    console.log("Error. Error. Error.");

}
```

The correct usage of the `if` syntax is:

```
if (condition) {
   // Do something here
} else {
   // For instances where the condition hasn't met do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `;` from

```
If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon `;` at the end of if statement.

Change

```
If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);
```

To

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` is in lowercase, and you need to remove the semicolon at the end of the if line.

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6) {
    console.log("The answer makes sense!");
} else {

    console.log("Error. Error. Error.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a semicolon to much. it should be:

```
if (boolean statement) {
//do sth
}
else { }
```

currently your if statement ends directly after the boolean statement

Comment: That's helpful Vogel612

Comment: @user3106983 you don't actually need to thank everyone who posted an answer.. people who post answer generally assume they are helpful. you should only comment, if that is not the case, but also give the reasons why then. they can improve their answer if you do it right, and it probably helps then

Answer (score 0):

remove the semicolon behind

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6)**;**
```

additional write in in lower characters

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons in JavaScript are used to seperate statements!

In that case, **remove the semicolon** from this line and ensure `if` **is in lowercase**:

```
if("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);
```

[More on if/else statement syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon (;) separates JavaScript statements.

Normally you add a semicolon at the end of each executable statement.

Using semicolons also make it possible to write many statements on one line.

You have to remove the semicolon in your if statement.

Change your code

From

```
If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6);
```

To

```
If("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 6)
```

And please check out [if.. else statement in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).